About CXL controller implementation
I'm working on CXL simulator design.
The simulator is cycle accurate, functional level rather than RTL or detailed micro-architectural level.
And I hope the simulator to be configurable so that various parameters can be configured by user.
Parameters I'm thinking of are retry-buffer size, controller IP's operating frequency, and more.
The problem is that I can't find reference information about controller IP's specification.
And I'm especially looking for CXL controller IP's operating clock frequency.
I think IP's logic that are part of transaction/link layer should have some range of configurability, but not sure where to set those range.
I've searched some vendors IP introduction documentations, but there are not much information about it.
Can you guys give me some reference, information or anything about CXL controller operating frequency setting?
Thanks in advance.
